# Facebook API scope

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Using the `base_facebook.php` and `facebook.php` I forgot to define a scope and ran this:

```php
$app_id = "11111111111";
$app_secret = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                        'appId' => $app_id,
                        'secret' => $app_secret,
                        'cookie' => true
                        ));
if(!($facebook->getUser()))
{
        header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos'))}");
        exit;
}
```

**Edit** I changed the header line to the following one with no luck:

```
header('Location:'.$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => $scope)));
```

First time I visited the page I got redirected to a place that asked me to accept this app. I did and the rest worked correctly.

Now I realize that I needed to define a scope, so I added a comma separated string, such as `user_checkins` but refreshing the page doesn't ask for extra agreement, nor does it allow me to view my checkins.

```
$scope = 'user_checkins,user_likes';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                        'appId' => $app_id,
                        'secret' => $app_secret,
                        'cookie' => true,
                        'scope' => $scope
                        ));
```

Am I missing something trivial? I tried resetting the app secret, but that did nothing. Also I can't find a decent tutorial :(

Thanks in advance!

**Answer**: Adding `scope` in `new Facebook()` doesn't do anything! Error was that using getLoginUrl() passed `req_perms` and needed to pass `scope` :

```
 header('Location:'.$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $scope)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is something easy, just go to your account in facebook and in your privacy settings go to your "apps and websites" and delete the current settings for your desire app, now try again it will have to prompt you for your permissions in the news extended perms, good luck, let me know if it works :)

Comment: Doing that lets me to re-allow permissions, but they are still not inclusive. I noticed that the code I copied from a tutorial uses getLoginUrl() with parameters written in. But replacing those with $scope didn't help either!